# Sanitize batch inputs against quotation marks?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
Rem ask for user input
set /p installerchoice= Please enter number for installer you wish to use:

Rem check to make sure input is a number
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%n in ("%installerchoice%") do set "var=%%n"
if defined var Goto Choose

rem check to make sure input is not zero
if %installerchoice% equ 0 goto Choose

rem check to make sure input isn't to high
if %installerchoice% gtr %Count% goto Choose
lection=%%i
```

I'm trying to make sure a valid input (a numerical value between 1 and how ever many options there are) is input. The only thing that seems to cause a problem right now is if a " is entered.  Is there anyway to prevent that from crashing the bat?

Comment: Yes, just enable [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) before the `for /F` loop and use it for variable `!installerchoice!`. then any `"` is no longer recognised by the parser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd tackle the task in your code:

```bat
:Choose
@Set "InstallerChoice="
@Set /P "InstallerChoice=Please enter the number for the installer you wish to use: "
@SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@(Echo(!InstallerChoice!|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /RX "[123456789][0123456789]* 0">NUL||(EndLocal&Goto Choose)) 2>NUL
@EndLocal
@Echo Your number %InstallerChoice% is valid.
@Pause
```

*However, had you provided the rest of the code, which I assume has parsed a directory within a for loop and allocated filenames to numbers in a menu like manner, there may have been a better or different methodology.*

Comment: The character ranges `[1-9]` and `[0-9]` would also allow some extended characters, like `²` and `³` in German locales, for instance, hence you should use `[123456789]` and `[0123456789]` instead, respectively...

Comment: I'm actually pretty embarrassed about the rest of the code and been thinking of a rewrite to powershell.  For now though, I have a unknown number of installers that will be in a directory, and want to present a menu asking which one to install of there is more then one. I've updated the original post with the relevant code.

Comment: @FrostyWolf, whilst it's admirable that you have now provided more code/context, you already have answers based upon your initial post. Changing the question is now outside of the scope of those answers and therefore unfair to the members who offered solutions. I would suggest that you roll back your edit, to keep the questions and answers better aligned for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

For Single Digit input, Use Choice

```
CHOICE /N /C 123456789 /M "Select Installer Number 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
GOTO :installer%errorlevel%
```

And use labels for your Installers such as:

```
:installer1
::commands

:installer2
::commands
```

To offer More options and Flexibility, Make Use of an Input Validation Function

```
@ECHO OFF
::: REM Delayed expansion is required only for testing of Second Call Parameter
::: Is not required if that testing is removed.
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::: REM The below 6 lines allow testing of the function, and are not part of the function.
:start
cls
CALL :Filter option number
ECHO %option%
pause
GOTO :start

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Function by T3RRY
::: Using this Function-
::: When Needing User Input:
:::
::: CALL :Filter <VarName> <AllowType>
::: Where <VarName> is replaced with the Variable name to be Set
::: And <AllowType> is replaced with letter, number, or alphanumerical

:Filter

::: Assign the variable (Passed by call Argument) to be set and tested

SET "testinput=%1"
SET "permitted=%~2"

::: Test Parameter Usage is Correct- For Debugging Only.

IF NOT DEFINED testinput (
ECHO Improper use of Filter Function. CALL :Filter must include a Parameter to define the Variable to be Set
Pause
Exit
)

Set P_True=0
IF DEFINED permitted (
    IF /I "%permitted%"=="number" Set /a P_True+=1
    IF /I "%permitted%"=="letter" Set /a P_True+=1
    IF /I "%permitted%"=="alphanumerical" Set /a P_True+=1
    IF "!P_True!"=="0" (
    ECHO Incorrect Parameter used for CALL :Filter 2nd Call Parameter.
    ECHO Parameter may be undefined, If Defined must include "number" OR "letter" OR "alphanumerical"
    Pause
    Exit
    )
)

::: Expand testinput to the Name of the Variable to be Assigned, Ensures Undefined

SET %testinput%=

::: Ensure Undefined Value for Input

SET input=

:Get_Input

::: Exit Filter once Acceptable Variable is Set

IF DEFINED input GOTO return

::: Create and start VBS script to Launch an Input Box and Store the input to text file for retrieval from this Batch program.

SET /P input=[Select %testinput%:]

::: Test to ensure Variable defined. Needed here to prevent environment variable not defined message ahead of next test Should the variable not be defined.

IF NOT DEFINED input GOTO invInput

::: Test for Doublequotes and reset variable if present

SET Input | FIND """" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET Input=

IF NOT DEFINED input GOTO invInput

:: REM Block Tilde

SET Input | FIND "~" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET Input=

IF NOT DEFINED input GOTO invInput

::: Test for Spaces

IF NOT "%input%"=="%input: =%" GOTO invInput

::: Test for all other standard Symbols.
::: To permit symbols REM out permitted Symbol and Call Filter without Second Parameter.

IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:&=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:(=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:)=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:<=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:>=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:{=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:}=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:]=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:[=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:#=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:^=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:+=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:-=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:/=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:\=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:|=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:$=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:!=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:?=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:@=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:'=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:,=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:.=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:;=%" GOTO invInput
IF NOT "%input%"=="%input:`=%" GOTO invInput

:: REM Length restriction. Adjust the length (Number) or Rem out as Desired

::: IF NOT "%input:~12%"=="" GOTO invInput

IF NOT DEFINED permitted GOTO :Get_Input
IF /I "%permitted%"=="number" GOTO :P_numbers
IF /I "%permitted%"=="letter" GOTO :P_letters
IF /I "%permitted%"=="alphanumerical" GOTO :P_alphanumerical

::: REM Permit only Numbers, Letters, or Letters and Numbers. Also Blocks *,! and %

:P_numbers
echo.%input%| findstr /R "[^0-9]" >nul 2>nul
if NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO invInput
GOTO :Get_Input

:P_letters
echo.%input%| findstr /R "[^a-zA-Z]" >nul 2>nul
if NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO invInput
GOTO :Get_Input

:P_alphanumerical
echo.%input%| findstr /R "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" >nul 2>nul
if NOT errorlevel 1 GOTO invInput
GOTO :Get_Input

:invInput

SET input=

::: REM Specifies the permitted input types.

IF DEFINED permitted (
    ECHO Input of %permitted% characters is allowed. Other Symbols and Characters are Not Permitted.
) else (
ECHO Invalid Character Entered. Try Again
)

GOTO :Get_Input

:return

::: assigns the input value to the variable name being validated.

SET "%testinput%=%input%"

SET input=

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: The steps used within the Filter function ensure that input of characters such as < > & etc never result in script failure. it is also a simple matter to adjust the permitted types of input by remming in or out input restrictions

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple: just enable [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) before the `for /F` loop and use it for variable `!InstallerChoice!`, then any `"` the user enters is no longer recognised by the parser:

```cmd
:Choose
set "InstallerChoice=" & rem // (reset variable to avoid keeping previous value)
set /P InstallerChoice="Please enter number for installer you wish to use: "

rem // Check to make sure input is a number:
set "var=" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=0 delims=0123456789" %%N in ("!InstallerChoice!") do set "var=%%N"
if defined var (endlocal & Goto Choose) else endlocal

rem // Check to make sure input is not zero:
if %InstallerChoice% equ 0 goto Choose

rem // Check to make sure input isn't to high:
if %InstallerChoice% gtr %Count% goto Choose
```

By the way, let me recommend to put `set "InstallerChoice="` just before `set /P`, because when the user just presses *{Enter}*, the previous value is going to be kept otherwise.
And you should add `eol=0` to the `for /F` loop options to not come into trouble when the user enters something beginning with the default `eol` character `;`.